# Return to previous level with early return

Tags: javascript, if-statement, return

```js
function myFunc() {
  if (1 == 1) {
    console.log('1 == 1')
    if (2 == 2) return
    console.log('2 !== 2')
    ///other code
  }
  if (3 == 3) {
    console.log('3 == 3')
  }
}
myFunc()
```

For this function, I am trying to say "if `2 == 2`, you can exit early from the current `if` block and return to the previous level. Then continue executing the next block (`if (3 == 3){...}`)." But the return function directly exits the entire function. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: 1==1 will always return true.  The kind of branching you are trying to do is similar to using goto and label:, which I greatly recommend you do not do.  Behavior and program flow is very difficult to reason about for anything even a little bit complicated.

Comment: That's what `return` is defined to do, it returns from the function. There's nothing that just exits from a level of `if`.

Comment: @TalmacelMarianSilviu `break` is only for loops, not `if`.

Comment: How about `if (2 !== 2) { /* other code */ }`

Comment: @user120242 Not to mention JavaScript doesn't have `goto`.

Comment: lol, one simple ugly solution, `if (2 == 2) { doSomethingSameInIf3Equal3(); return; }`.

Comment: Consider using `switch`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an IIFE. `return` will return from the IIFE, not the containing function:

```js
function myFunc() {
  if (1 == 1) {
    console.log('1 == 1');
    (function() {
      if (2 == 2) return;
      console.log('2 !== 2')
    })();
  }
  if (3 == 3) {
    console.log('3 == 3');
  }
}
myFunc();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it would be to not enter the first if condition in the first place. If you want to run code if 1==1 except when 2==2 I would use:

```
function myFunc() {
  if (1 == 1 && 2!==2) {
    console.log('1 == 1')

    ///other code
  }
  if (3 == 3) {
    console.log('3 == 3')
  }
}
myFunc()
```

Answer (score 0):

As @user120242 said 1==1 is always true and using goto and label is not efficient and not recommended at all.

For your problem you can use multiple functions. Each function checks something
This may be one approach to solve it:

```
function myFunc() {
 if (1 == 1) {
  console.log("1==1");
  if( 2 == 2 ) { // can also get an own function
   callNextFunc(); // contains the 3==3 function
   return;
  }
  else {
   console.log("2!=2");
   // other code
   callNextFunc();
  }
 }
}
```

Using functions lets you return and skip some parts of the code easily.

Answer (score 0):

Although a bit hacky!!, you could maybe use a switch, case..

eg..

```js
function myFunc() {
  switch (1) {
    case 1: {
      console.log('1 == 1')
      if (2 === 2) break;
      console.log('2 !== 2')
    }
  }
  if (3 == 3) {
    console.log('3 == 3')
  }
}
myFunc()
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use `switch` as I've suggested in my comment and then used by someone in their answer, or modify the code by replacing `return` with `;` and wrapping the rest with `{}` prepended with `else`...

### **AND USE SEMICOLONS!!!**

```js
function myFunc() {
  if (1 == 1) {
    console.log('1 == 1');
    if (2 == 2) ;
    else {
      console.log('2 !== 2');
      ///other code
    }
  }
  if (3 == 3) {
    console.log('3 == 3');
  }
};
myFunc();
```